# Automatically dismount specific TrueCrypt volume in Windows

Tags: windows, truecrypt

Is it possible to specify in TrueCrypt (under Windows) that some specific (not all) mounted volume has to be automatically dismounted after some period of time? In the settings I can only set auto dismount to apply to *all* volumes.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which volume it is, you can dismount it from the command line: The following command dismounts a TrueCrypt volume mounted to drive S:

> truecrypt.exe /d s /q

Note that this is interactive, and will fail if a file on the volume is open. Use /f to force a dismount.

The following mounts X.TC to drive S:

> truecrypt.exe /v x.tc /q /ls /e /b /m ts

I use batch files to do this every day. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I think this could be useful. I would like to dismount the volume after a certain time of inactivity (no reads/writes to the mounted drive). Perhaps I achieve this with the scheduler in Windows to run a dismount script.